# TypeScript type inference issue

Tags: typescript, type-inference, type-safety

I'm using TypeScript with the MongoDB node.js driver. Note, this is not a Mongo question, its just the particular use case of this issue I'm having.

Pretty much every Mongo call uses a pattern of `(arg1, arg2, ..., argn, callback)` where `callback` is a function that accepts `(err, res)`. However, I want to use promises. I'm trying to simplify my usage by writing a helper wrapper function, like so:

```
function mongoWrap<T>(action: (callback: (err: Error, res: T) => void) => void) : q.IPromise<T>
{
    var promise = q.Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => {
       action((err, res) => {
           if (err) reject(err);
           else resolve(res);
       });
    });

    return promise;
}
```

This works great, except that for some reason the compiler cannot infer the type of `T`. I have to make calls such as:

```
var dbPromise = mongoWrap<mongodb.Db>(cb => mongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/database", cb));
```

If I omit the `<mongodb.Db>` part, the result is `Promise<{}>` and I lose type safety. However, the compiler clearly knows that the `callback` argument to the Mongo call is `(err: Error, db: Db) => void`.

What can I do to get the compiler to correctly infer the type of `T`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typescript is able to infer the type of some generic functions but it has some limitations.

Since there isn't any information in the [generic section of the handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#generics) I decided to make some tests and see where it breaks down.

1. a simple function that takes 1 parameter.

```js
function genericFunction<T>(value: T): T {
    return value;
}

// type of val is Window
let val = genericFunction(window);
```

This works, there's no need to specify the type of T manually.

2. a function with 2 generic parameters.

```js
function genericFunction2<T>(value: T, anotherValue: T) : T {
    return value;
}

// type of val is String
let val = genericFunction2("b", "5"); 

// compilation error type of T can't be inferred from usage
let anotherVal = genericFunction2("b", 5);
```

This works, there's no need to specify the type of T manually.

3. a function that receives a callback and a value.

```js
function callBackAndValue<T>(action: (value: T) => T, value: T): T {
    return action(value);
}

// type of val is string
let val = callBackAndValue((value: string) => value + "5", "abc ");
```

This works, there's no need to specify the type of T manually.

4. a function that receives a callback and a value but returns a promise.

```js
function callBackAndValueWithPromise<T>(action: (value: T) => T, value: T): Promise<T> {
    return new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(action(value));
    });
}

// type of val is Promise<string>
let val = callBackAndValueWithPromise((value: string) => value + "5", "abc ");
```

This works, there's no need to specify the type of T manually.

5. a function that receives only a function from T to T

```js
function onlyCallback<T>(action: () => T) : T {
    return action();
}

// type of val is string
let val = onlyCallback(()=> "abc");
```

This works, there's no need to specify the type of T manually.

6. A function that receives a function from nothing to T that returns a promise.

```js
function onlyCallbackWithPromise<T>(action: () => T): Promise<T> {
    return new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => { 
        resolve(action());
    });
}

// the type of val is Promise<string>
let val = onlyCallbackWithPromise(()=> "abc");
```

This works, there's no need to specify the type of T manually.

7. A function that receives the a function that takes a function.  The case in the question.

```js
function typeFromCallbackOfCallback<T>(action: (callback: (value: T) => void) => void): Promise<T> {
    return new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => {
        action((value) => {
            resolve(value);
        });
    });
}

// here the compiler fails to infer the type cb should take as a parameter and it seems to default to object({})
// type of Val is Promise<{}>
let val = typeFromCallbackOfCallback(cb => cb("abc"));
```

This no longer works and needs the type to be specified manually.

Since the compiler is limited at the moment I guess you are stuck having to specify the type for this case. That is the solution given in the handbook as well for the cases when type inference fails.

Adding another parameter of type T fixes it, but It doesn't quite match your case.

```js
function lastOne<T>(action: (callback: (value: T) => void) => void, b: T): Promise<T> {
    return new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => {
        action((value) => {
            resolve(value);
        });
    });
}

// type of var is Promise<string>
let var = lastOne(cb => cb("abc"), "a");
```

This works, there's no need to specify the type of T manually.

Comment: Why wouldn't there be a single way to determine the type of T? There's only one use of it in the args.

Comment: FWIW I'm coming from C# where this would have worked just fine via type inference. Its not a uniqueness issue.

Comment: Sadly type inference in TypeScript is not as advanced as C#, and at the moment it needs you to specify the type for generic functions. Regarding uniqueness I was trying to say it makes it easier for the compiler to determine the type (it doesn't really need to if you specify it). Looking back that phrase is not very well worded though, I will change it. :)

Comment: It looks like TypeScript has some type inference after all, but it seems to stop working exactly at the level of a determining the type of T from a the parameter of a callback given to a function received as a parameter. :(

Comment: just for completion C# can't infer the type from the callback on it's own either. It does at least generate a compilation error, and asks you to specify the generic type manually. At least if what I wrote here is correct. http://goo.gl/nEVXo0

Answer (score 1):

I was wrong, this doesn't work in C# either. Here's the example of the same code from TypeScript, written in C#, that does not work:

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        var task = Wrapper(cb => FakeMongoFunctionWithCallback(5, cb));
    }

    static void FakeMongoFunctionWithCallback(int arg, Action<Exception, int> callback)
    {
        // just pass through the arg into the callback, pretending we went to a db and came back with that result
        callback(null, arg);
    }

    static Task<T> Wrapper<T>(Action<Action<Exception, T>> action) {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
        action((err, res) => {
            if (err != null) tcs.SetException(err);
            else tcs.SetResult(res);
        });

        return tcs.Task;
    } 
}
```

Comment: it's just too deep for the compiler to get it. :(