# Type inference for functions passed to generic function wrappers like _.debounce

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics

In TypeScript, if a function expression is passed as an argument, the types of its parameters are inferred perfectly:

```
var foo = (fn: (a: string) => void) => {};

foo(a => { 
    // a is inferred to be a string
    alert(a.toLowerCase());
});
```

It's really convenient for event handlers and other callbacks. However, if the function expression is wrapped in a call of a generic wrapper function, which takes a function as a parameter and returns a function with the same signature (except for return value), e.g. `_.debounce` of Lodash, the inference doesn't happen.

```
var debounce = <T>(fn: (a: T) => void) => {
    return (a: T) => { /* ... */ };
};

foo(debounce(a => { 
    // a is inferred to be {}
    // type error: 'toLowerCase' doesn't exist on '{}'
    alert(a.toLowerCase());
}));
```

[TS Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=var%20foo%20%3D%20(fn%3A%20(a%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20void)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%0Afoo(a%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%0A%09%2F%2F%20a%20is%20inferred%20to%20be%20a%20string%0A%09alert(a.toLowerCase())%3B%0A%7D)%3B%20%0A%0Avar%20debounce%20%3D%20%3CT%3E(fn%3A%20(a%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20void)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(a%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%2F*%20...%20*%2F%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Afoo(debounce(a%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20a%20is%20inferred%20to%20be%20%7B%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20type%20error%3A%20'toLowerCase'%20doesn't%20exist%20on%20'%7B%7D'%0A%20%20%20%20alert(a.toLowerCase())%3B%0A%7D))%3B)

As `foo` wants its argument to be `(a: string) => void`, the compiler could try to find such a type for `T` that `debounce<T>` would return `(a: string) => void`. But it doesn't try to do this.

Am I missing something? Should I have written the type annotations for `debounce` somehow else? Is it by design? Is there an issue on GitHub about this case?

**UPDATE-2017:** It works now! TS 2.5.

Comment: I think that's just a limitation of the type inference system. It can't deduce the type of a generic function based only based on the argument of a function received as a parameter. I explored the issue more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34531390/typescript-type-inference-issue/34533133#34533133

Comment: Don't think it's the same issue. I didn't expect it to deduce the type of the generic function from the parameters. I expected the inference to happen in the opposite direction, from the root of the AST to its leaves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, when you call a generic function without type arguments, the compiler has to figure out the type for each type parameter.

So when you call `debounce`, the compiler has to find candidates for the type of `T`. But the only place `debounce` can draw inferences from is your function, and you didn't give an explicit type for your type parameter.

So the compiler figures it doesn't have any types to work with, and falls back to `{}` (the "empty type", often just called "curly curly") for `T`.

That whole process is called *type argument inference*.

What then happens is that the compiler will notice that you haven't given your arrow function's parameters a type. Rather than defaulting to `any`, it figures that it can figure it out from the type of `debounce`'s parameters. This process is called *contextual typing*.

Well `fn`'s type is basically `(a: {}) => void`, so the compiler figures "alright, great, we can give `a` a type!" which ends up being... `{}` unfortunately.

---

So while this isn't totally absolutely awesome, the fix isn't really that bad. Just add a type annotation for `a`:

```
foo(debounce((a: string) => { 
    // Everything is fine!
    alert(a.toLowerCase());
}));
```

or use a type parameter:

```
foo(debounce<string>(a => { 
    // Everything is fine!
    alert(a.toLowerCase());
}));
```

Comment: At least we get `{}`, not `any`, so this situation doesn't go unnoticed. Still, it's kind of strange that the type for `T` is inferred from `a` and vice versa.  "The only place `debounce` can draw inferences from is your function..." It could also try to draw them from the type of `foo`'s parameter. And that was my question. I wanted to make sure TS doesn't do this. Thank you for clarifying.